# Loading .Net Framework types inside .NET Core 1.1 Application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017, I have created an ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework).  Installed the NuGets for the .NET Framework 4.5.2 dependencies, built, and published the application to my Windows Server box where I have the .NET Core 1.1.1 RunTime installed.  I run my app and get the following:

```
PS C:\Performance_App\v.0.0.1> .\EPiServer.Social.Testing.Performance.Application
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Performance_App\v.0.0.1
Now listening on: http://*:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://socialvm2.ep.se:5000/api/comments multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycVrgT9gRbDmTFv78 946
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action EPiServer.Social.Testing.Performance.Application.Controllers.CommentsController.Post (EPiServer.Social.Testing.Performance.Application) in 168.0949ms
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL3IML91HVGN": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'EPiServer.Social.Common.Rest.ResponseMessageHandler' from assembly 'EPiServer.Social.Common.Rest, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7'.
   at EPiServer.Social.Comments.Rest.HttpCommentRepository..ctor(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, ICommentRequestFactory requestFactory)
   at EPiServer.Social.Comments.DefaultCommentServiceFactory.GetRepository()
   at EPiServer.Social.Comments.DefaultCommentServiceFactory.Create()
   at EPiServer.Social.Testing.Performance.Application.Controllers.CommentsController..ctor()
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.TypeActivatorCache.CreateInstance[TInstance](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type implementationType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(ControllerContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

The .NET Framework dependency tree looks good:

[image]

Any ideas as to what this particular problem may be?

Comment: fyi, I don't even need to publish.  Running the app in debug mode under visual studio 2017 exhibits the same problem.  Does this mean that .NET Core 1.1 and .NET Framework 4.5.2 are incompatible?

Comment: This was a dependency issue.  When I installed EPiServer.SocialComments it seems to also have installed its dependencies such as EPiServer.Social.Common.Rest, which can be observed in the image in the OP.  However, when I went back to check the the installed packages in NuGet manager it didn't show any of those sub-dependencies as been installed.  Installing them at the project level resolved the issue.  Not sure what's up with that.

Comment: Please stop mixing ASP.NET Core and .NET Core. ASP.NET Core is a webstack for creating MVC/REST services, .NET Core is a runtime like JVM or the full .NET Framework (4.6) on Desktop. ASP.NET Core can run on both. And yes, .NET Core and .NET Framework are incompatible, because it's different runtimes. But ASP.NET Core can run on both! When you run "ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)" you need .NET Framework installed, **NOT .NET Core**